# Динамически задать условия для фильтрации DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, условия, dataframe, фильтрация

Делаю с помощью `dash` небольшой модуль для расчётов. В нем присутствует таблица, в которую выводятся отфильтрованные данные из `pandas.dataframe`.

Есть список из 10 переменных `(значение из дропбокса)`, которые передаются в функцию `(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)`. Как автоматизировать такой перебор, чтобы выполнялось такое условие (псевдокод):

```
if a == a and (b is None or len(b) ==0) and (c is None or len(c) ==0) and ... (j is None or len(j)== 0):
  return df(df[df[a].isin(a)).to_dict('records')

if a == a and b == b (c is None or len(c) ==0) and (d is None or len(d) ==0) and ... (j is None or len(j)== 0):
  return df[(df[a].isin(a)) &
 (df[b].isin(b))].to_dict('records')
```

То есть, если выбирается  значение из одного дропбокса, то `dataframe` фильтруется по этому значению, а остальные не учитываются; если из двух, то, соответственно, фильтруется по этим двум значениям, остальные не учитываются и т.д.

Вручную задать для каждого `a b c... это же больше 10!`, что точно ошибочно.

Как ни пытался использовать `for i in list`, но не выходит.

Comment: Попробуйте создать ["минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Дальше if a==a вряд что-то сравниваться будет.

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

исходный DataFrame:

```
In [42]: np.random.seed(123)

In [43]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(8, size=(20,10)), columns=list('abcdefghij'))

In [44]: df
Out[44]:
    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
0   6  5  6  2  4  2  6  1  3  2
1   3  1  6  1  0  1  6  7  1  0
2   6  0  7  1  3  6  5  4  0  0
3   4  1  7  3  2  4  7  2  4  7
4   0  5  0  7  1  3  4  4  4  6
5   1  5  6  6  3  2  1  4  0  3
6   2  5  0  3  2  2  2  6  5  2
7   4  7  3  3  5  4  6  4  6  5
8   3  2  0  6  6  7  4  7  3  6
9   7  1  3  2  5  7  1  2  4  0
10  1  4  2  1  1  3  4  5  1  0
11  0  3  1  6  3  3  3  5  1  7
12  1  2  3  3  3  3  0  6  6  1
13  7  6  6  3  1  6  4  6  3  6
14  1  5  6  2  3  4  3  1  7  5
15  0  5  0  5  6  6  7  3  0  1
16  5  1  0  3  5  1  3  4  6  7
17  5  6  4  1  4  6  4  3  4  3
18  7  6  0  6  5  4  4  7  4  4
19  7  0  0  1  0  0  4  2  7  2
```

словарь с условиями для фильтрации:

```
In [45]: conds = dict(a=[0,1,7], b=[0,1,7], f=[0,6,7])

In [46]: conds
Out[46]: {'a': [0, 1, 7], 'b': [0, 1, 7], 'f': [0, 6, 7]}
```

создаем SQL-подобный запрос для [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
In [47]: q = ' and '.join(['{} in @conds.get("{}")'.format(k,k) for k in conds.keys()])

In [48]: q
Out[48]: 'a in @conds.get("a") and b in @conds.get("b") and f in @conds.get("f")'
```

результат:

```
In [49]: df.query(q)
Out[49]:
    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
9   7  1  3  2  5  7  1  2  4  0
19  7  0  0  1  0  0  4  2  7  2
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Это помогло!

Comment: @Wittgenstein, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814) ;-)